# Flutter: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Model>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Flutter and I'm stuck.

Context: I'm fetching a list of data from Firestore:

```dart
Future<List<AccountGroup>> fetchAccountGroup() async {
    final res = await ref.get();
    return res.docs
        .map((doc) => AccountGroup(
            id: doc.id, title: doc.data().title, accounts: doc.data().accounts))
        .toList();
  }
```

Using this model:

```dart
import 'package:budget_er/models/account.dart';

class AccountGroup {
  final String? id;
  final String title;
  final List<Account> accounts;

  AccountGroup({this.id, required this.title, required this.accounts});

  AccountGroup.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : this(
          title: json['title']! as String,
          accounts: json['accounts'] as List<Account>,
        );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'title': title,
      'accounts': accounts,
    };
  }
}
```

This is the Account model that I'm trying to cast to `json['accounts']`.

```dart
class Account {
  int balance;
  String label;
  String accountGroupId;

  Account(
      {required this.balance,
      required this.label,
      required this.accountGroupId});

  Account.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      : balance = json['balance'] as int,
        label = json['label'] as String,
        accountGroupId = json['accountGroup'] as String;

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      "balance": balance,
      "label": label,
      "accountGroupId": accountGroupId
    };
  }
}
```

however it produces this error:

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state:
_FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#692ef):
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Account>' of 'function result'
```

I'm rendering the fetched data like this:

```dart
final renderGroups = groups.map((group) => Row(
                children: [
                  Text(group.title),
                  ...group.accounts.map((account) {
                    return SummaryItem(
                        balance: formatMoney(account.balance),
                        label: account.label);
                  })
                ],
              ));
```

I tried casting it with `as` just like in TypeScript but to no effect. Thanks!

Comment: provider your json string

Answer (score 0):

Probably a noob mistake.

- The error basically says that I have the wrong subtype.
- So on my fetch method, I mapped the property that has an error and create a new list of objects using the Model (`Account`) class.

Like this:

```dart
Future<List<AccountGroup>> fetchAccountGroup() async {
    final res = await ref.get();
    return res.docs.map((doc) {
      final data = doc.data();

      final newAccounts = data.accounts.map((account) {
        return Account(
            balance: account['balance'],
            label: account['label'],
            accountGroupId: account['accountGroupId']);
      }).toList();

      return AccountGroup(id: doc.id, title: data.title, accounts: newAccounts);
    }).toList();
  }
```